# How can I have a pair with reference inside vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, unique-ptr

I really need to make `std::vector` of `std::pair` with reference (`&`) inside, but it breaks inside the function when I try to `push_back` reference value. After debugging I discovered, that the address of reference is different from the address inside `unique_ptr` (but the value is the same).

When I don't use (here the foo()) any function that insert into vector it's the value it refers to is correct, but the addresses still don't match.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void foo(std::vector<std::pair<const int&, int> >& vector,         
std::unique_ptr<int>& ptr) {
    vector.push_back(std::make_pair<const int&, int>(*ptr, 11));
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<const int&, int> > v;
    std::unique_ptr<int> i = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    std::unique_ptr<int> b = std::make_unique<int>(0);   
    foo(v, i);
    v.push_back(std::make_pair<const int&, int>(*b, 10));
    std::cout << v.size() << ": ";
    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x.first << ",";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

This code demonstrates the problem - instead of `"2: 1,0,"` it outputs `"2: -342851272,0,"` (or similar big negative number in the first place).

Where is the problem?

Comment: [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Well, because they (it's school assignment) are testing the function and are expecting this return.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah, I would normally be more than glad to use this, but I don't have the option now.

Comment: A school assignment that allows for the use of the standard library? But not the part you actually seem to need? Well, I guess you are going about the assignment all wrong then.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's...quite possible.

Comment: Possibly you have misunderstood the assignment.

Comment: Why not use a pointer rather than a reference?

Comment: I think you need to tell us what the assignment is, verbatim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++14 `std::make_pair` is defined as

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );
```

where `V1` and `V2` are `std::decay<T1>::type` and `std::decay<T2>::type` respectively.

This means that your `make_pair<const int&, int>` calls do not really produce pairs with references as their first elements (contrary to what you apparently believed). They actually produce temporaries of `pair<int, int>` type. At this point you lose any attachment to the original `int` object stored in your `unique_ptr`.

When you pass these `pair<int, int>` temporaries to `push_back`, they get implicitly converted to temporaries of `pair<const int&, int>` type, which is your vector's element type. Through this mechanism you attach references inside your vector's element to `int` members of those `pair<int, int>` temporaries produced by `make_pair` (not to `int` objects stored in your `unique_ptr`s). Once the temporaries expire, the references go sour.

---

In this case you can eliminate this specific problem by avoiding `make_pair` altogether and simply directly constructing `std::pair` objects of proper type, e.g.

```
vector.push_back(std::pair<const int&, int>(*ptr, 11));
```

but you might run into other problems caused by raw references later.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying the direct construction and it's working so far, (EDIT: Yeah, the inserted reference address is the actually the same as the unique_ptr.get() now)  can you please explain why exactly it's working? 
And by the problem of raw reference later, it's "just" about them possibly pointing to nowhere, not about interfering with `unique_ptr` memory management, right?