# Retrieval of value back from C++ map<T, const T&> returns same object

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I created a map of type `map<T, const T&>`. For current example purpose, let say `T` is:

```
class Bar {
public:
  Bar(int x) {this->x = x;}
  int x;
};
```

Next I create a map and insert `Bar` keyed with some integers.

```
Bar bs[] = {Bar(1), Bar(2), Bar(3)};
map<int, const Bar&> my_map;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const Bar &b = bs[i];
  cout << "Setting map." << i
       << " with x = " << b.x << endl ;
  my_map.insert(std::make_pair(i, b));
}
```

So far everything looks good, and `b.x` prints the values `1; 2; 3` as expected. Next we retrieve these values back.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  auto iter = my_map.find(i);
  if (iter == my_map.end()) {
    cout << "Not found!" << endl;
    continue;
  }
  cout << "map." << i << " = " << iter->second.x << endl;
}
```

The output prints the last value each time as shown below.

```
//   map.0 = 3
//   map.1 = 3
//   map.2 = 3
```

And that's what is confusing to me, as I expect `1; 2; 3`. If I replace value type of map with just `const Bar` it gives `1; 2; 3`. I've been trying to make sense out of it, but so far it just looks like undefined behaviour to me. The wildest explanation I can imagine is that `&b` is like a box storing pointer to the object, and the box ends up being shared across loop, and `make_pair` uses `&b` as a box value than like a pointer/reference (and hence explains the last value being printed).

**Edit:** I understand it may not be good idea to use map like this, but I'm curious why this is happening than what should I be using instead. As in semantically, what did I miss when I wrote this and why it went through compiler, or why compiler made whatever assumption it made.

**Edit:** Example on repl.it running the code: https://repl.it/repls/IgnorantExhaustedBluejay

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's ill-formed to have a map of references. I'm surprised it even compiles for you; it doesn't for me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Here's the program on repl.it https://repl.it/repls/IgnorantExhaustedBluejay

Comment: I can compile that code on ideone.com (g++ 6.3) but if I try to access the the map index directly with `my_map[0]` if throws compilation error.

Answer (score 7):

Essentially the same problem as here: [How can I have a pair with reference inside vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849339/how-can-i-have-a-pair-with-reference-inside-vector/47849517#47849517)

Your call to `std::make_pair` creates a temporary `std::pair` object that does not have a reference as its second member. The `second` member of the pair is a regular value of type `Bar`. Meanwhile, your map stores references. The reference gets bound to the `second` member of the temporary created by `std::make_pair`. Later the temporary gets destroyed. The reference becomes dangling.

Each temporary on each iteration of the cycle is apparently created at the same location in memory. So, all these dangling references in your map refer to the same location in memory. Which just happens to hold the residual value of `3` at the time of printing. That explains the output.

A map with raw references is not a very good idea. But if you want to somehow force it to work with raw references, stop using `std::make_pair`. Instead, manually construct a proper `std::pair`, making sure to explicitly specify the proper types

```
my_map.insert(std::pair<const int, const Bar &b>(i, b));
```

Or you can keep using `std::make_pair` as follows

```
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(i, std::cref(b)));
```

But switching entirely to `std::reference_wrapper` and `std::cref` is a better idea.

P.S. BTW, in C++17 mode GCC refuses to compile the code with raw references. C++14 mode does compile it.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: "in C++17 mode GCC refuses to compile the code with raw references." This is [GCC bug 83226](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83226)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't even aware that it's possible to have a map of references
You should probably simply store the object you want directly :

```
map<int, Bar> my_map;
```

If you want the "Bar"s objects to live outside the map, you should use pointers instead of references. Just be sure you don't destruct the Bar objects without removing them from the map :

```
map<int, Bar*> my_map;
my_map[2] = &bs[0];
```

and then:

```
int x = my_map[2]->x;
```

**Edit**
I think the map is holding a reference to the temporary pair. You can see this in debug if you extract the creation of the pair :

```
    auto tempPair = std::make_pair(i, b);
    my_map.insert(tempPair);
```

Then after adding bs[0] if we run the creation of the pair, the value of my_map[0] change even before adding the second one:
[image]

Comment: I probably didn't frame my answer correctly. The reason I asked this question was not to get a workaround, but the explanation on why is this happening. I already fixed the problem, when I discovered the issue, but I couldn't give myself a convincing explanation on why this happened. Shouldn't the reference I put in point directly to the original object which lives?

Answer (score 0):

This makes it work:

```
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(i, std::reference_wrapper<const Bar>(b)));
```